# Nested Query Based on The Select Related in Django Models

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I have two models where the second has a dependency on the first. The Structure is as follows.

```
class Crop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

the other is

```
class Plotting(models.Model):
    crop = models.ForeignKey(
        Crop, on_delete=models.CASCADE, limit_choices_to={"is_active": True}
    )

    sowing_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    harvesting_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    acre = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0, help_text="Area in Acres"
    )
```

I want to fetch the data in the following format.

```
CROP NAME | JAN | FEB | MAR | APR | MAY
crop 1    | 20  | 10  | 35  | 45  | 35 
crop 2    | 20  | 10  | 35  | 45  | 35
crop 3    | 20  | 10  | 35  | 45  | 35
crop 4    | 20  | 10  | 35  | 45  | 35
```

CROP 1 JAN defines the sum of acres harvested in January based on the harvesting_date.
I also want to filter with dates and exclude the crops whose value is the sum of acres is 0.

Comment: Have you tried any queryset for this record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way to get the required data

```
p = Plotting.objects.all() # could filter for date and exclude acre == 0 
p = p.values('crop__name', 'harvesting_date__month').annotate(sum_of_acres=Sum('acre')).order_by('crop__name', harvesting_date__month')
```

in the template you could use regroup

Comment: Your answer helps me get the desired output up to some extent. I am able to get the required data but I am trying to optimize it more so that I won't have to process the data, instead query itself will give the complete response.

Comment: I am able to get [["Ledies Finger", 7, 12.0], ["Ledies Finger", 8, 0.17]] here 7 and 8 are the months and 12.0 and 0.17 are sums.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe queryset like this:

```
queryset = Crop.objects.values('name')
queryset = queryset.aggregate(harvesting_date_jan=Count('harvesting_date', filter=Q(harvesting_date__month=1)))
queryset = queryset.aggregate(harvesting_date_feb=Count('harvesting_date', filter=Q(harvesting_date__month=2)))
...
```